# What is the name for this error metric?

Tags: machine-learning, regularization

I am following a paper that says that a generalized learning method is optimized by minimizing a regularized error metric:

$$
H(f_\mathcal{G}) = (1-\lambda)||y_i-f_\mathcal{G}(\mathbf{x_i})||^2 + \lambda J(f_\mathcal{G}),
$$

Where the regularization function $J(f_\mathcal{G})$ is a term which penalizes the higher derivatives of $f_\mathcal{G}$ and $\lambda$ is the regularization constant bounded by $0<=\lambda<1$.

I am new to machine learning, so I am trying to understand where this formula comes from. For me, this looks like Tikhonov regularization however it includes a $(1-\lambda)$ term in front of the squared error. In addition, in Tikhonov regularization, $\lambda$ is only bounded by $>0$ (as far as I am aware). Is there a name for this regularization? I can't find it anywhere online. Why does there need to be a $(1-\lambda)$ term in front of the squared error?

In addition, the paper doesn't state what the $J(f_\mathcal{G})$ term could be. Is there a standard function for this term?

Comment: It seems that the authors are interested in prioritizing either the squared error loss ($\lambda = 0$), or $J(f_\mathcal{G})$ ($\lambda = 1$), or a convex combination of the two. In this case, I don't think $J(f_\mathcal{G})$ should be interpreted as a regularization function.

Comment: You are focusing on an irrelevancy, because it would be equivalent to optimize $(1+\alpha)H = ||\cdots||^2+\alpha J$ where $\alpha=\lambda/(1-\lambda)$ ranges from $0$ to$\infty.$ Thus, $J$ regularizes a standard $L_2$ criterion.